# Inject custom label into default jmx Prometheus metrics for Java client

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

Our system consists of multiple JAVA based microservices, each one reports its RT status leveraging [io.prometheus simpleclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient)

The integration code looks pretty straightforward

```
// Initialize default JVM metrics for Prometheus
    DefaultExports.initialize();

    DeploymentInfo monitoringServletInfo = Servlets.deployment()
            .setClassLoader(MonitoringServer.class.getClassLoader())
            .setContextPath("/")
            .setDeploymentName("monitoring")
            .addServlet(Servlets.servlet(MetricsServlet.class).addMapping("/*"));

    DeploymentManager monitoringDeployment = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(monitoringServletInfo);
    monitoringDeployment.deploy();
    HttpHandler monitoringHandler = monitoringDeployment.start();

    server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(port, "0.0.0.0")
            .setHandler(
                    Handlers.path().addExactPath(HEALTH_PATH, new HealthHandler())
                            .addExactPath(MONITORING_PATH, monitoringHandler))
            .build();

    server.start();
```

Since all microservices expose the same metrics name we are looking for a way to distinguish them by providing a custom label for each microservice

for example, this metrics has the following definition

```
jvm_buffer_pool_used_bytes{pool="direct",} 116776.0
```

our purpose is to add a custom label like, then it will be super easy to separate than in the Grafana.

```
jvm_buffer_pool_used_bytes{pool="direct",service="foo"} 116776.0
```

I want to believe the lib has to have such capability, unfortunately googling it for a while was not such successful

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stronly suggest to use [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) for that job. Which is

a) easier to integrate and

b) you can can also add so called
"[common tags](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_common_tags)" which is exactly what you are looking for (Micromether uses the term "tag" instead of "label" but the concept is the same).

```
registry.config().commonTags("service", "someService");
```

Especially for the "default" metrics that the JVM provides also via JMX it has an easy integration:

```
new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(registry);
```

and you got all the memory metrics in your prometheus metrics. (see [here](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/jvm) for more information)

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions, however, we can't use an alternative library.
Seems like I found the way to solve it by providing a custom MetricsServlet.class
Implementation.

Comment: just being curious, what hinders you using another library?

Comment: our system is based on tens of microservices. as far as I know, Micrometer uses slightly different metric names, moving to Micrometer means, unjustified code refactoring and Grafana dashboards ajustment, it's not worth it.

Comment: @DenisVoloshin How did you solve it using metricServelt as I am in same boat

Comment: Hey @RGoyal, it's been three years since I encountered this issue while working at my previous company. Regrettably, I can't recall the details of the custom MetricsServlet class or how we addressed the issue. Sorry man